# Problem in my test function trying to access group of routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware

What I'm trying to test is to access some routes but these routes are in laratrust role middleware this role is the auth user must be super admin to go in this routes my problem is I don't know how to write this function.

I tried to make the user super admin in the test function like this

```
public function  Test()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $user->attachRole('superadministrator');
    $this->actingAs($user, 'api');

    $response = $this->json('GET', 'api/users');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

but it didn't work even I checked the data base this user is superadministrator and the test give like I'm not super admin

This is my api routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'role:superadministrator']],
function()
{
    Route::apiResource('users', 'UserController');
}
```

This is my index function in UserController:

```
public function index()
{
    return Response()->json(User::all, 200);
}
```

What I'm expect is a function can access this route because there is more routes in this group and the rest of the tests depends on this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Laratrust, but after a quick look at its source code, it looks like the issue is that you need to specify the `api` guard on your `role` middleware check. Add `,guard:api` to your `role` middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'role:superadministrator,guard:api']], function() {
    Route::apiResource('users', 'UserController');
}
```

In the `role` middleware check, if you don't specify the guard, it will use the default guard defined in your auth config (which is `web` if you haven't changed it). So, the middleware will be looking for the user from the `web` auth guard, which doesn't exist.

The good news is, your test worked! It found a bug in your route definition.

Comment: The guard in web is the default the api is passport and also the middleware works just fine when I try it but I want to but under test

Comment: @ObitoPoseidon "middleware works just fine when I try it": if you're logged into your front end and accessing the route using a transient token from the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware, that will work just fine, since both your `web` guard and your `api` guard have the same user. In your test, however, you've only assigned the user to the `api` guard. Your `auth` middleware will pass, but your `role` middleware will fail since it is only checking the `web` guard. Since your route is restricted to the `api` guard (`auth:api`), you really should add the `api` guard to your `role` middleware.

Comment: ok how I can do that and my gaurds look like this 

web => [ 'driver' => 'session' , 'provider'=> 'user' ] 
api => [ 'driver' => 'passport' , 'provider' => 'users' , 'hash' => false ]

Comment: @ObitoPoseidon It's in my answer. Your middleware should be `'role:superadministrator,guard:api'`.

Comment: @ObitoPoseidon In the documentation, it's mentioned in the last paragraph of the [Usage > Middleware > Concepts](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/5.2/usage/middleware.html#concepts)

Comment: The last paragraph talk about redirect

Comment: @ObitoPoseidon "Redirect" is the last section under "Middleware". Look at the last part of the "Concepts" section.

Comment: Thanks you very mush